# do I have to reinstall tensorflow after changing gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, cudnn

I'm using tensorflow with gpu. My computer have NVIDIA gforce 750 ti  and I'm gonna replace it with 1080 ti. do I have to re install tensorflow(or other drivers etc.)? If it is true, what exactly do I have to re-install?

One more question, Can I speed up the training process by install one more gpu in the computer?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only thing you need to reinstall are the GPU drivers (CUDA an/or cuDNN). If you install the exact same version with the exact same bindings Tensorflow should not notice you changed the GPU and continue working...

And yes, you can speed up the training process with multiple GPUs, but telling you how to install and manage that is a bit too broad for a Stackoverflow answer....

Comment: Thanks! okay then, If I install two gpu and I don't do anything such as management of gpu . I just run tensorflow code just like I do when there was only one gpu. Then can tensorflow recognize two gpu and find the way to speed up the process with two gpus automatically?

Comment: Sorry, I guess you have to do GPU management... It is not exactly trivial to add another different GPU. Good luck!